# Use scala spark to read csv and get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am using spark in scala in Intellij, I use POM to import spark. Now I want to read a csv file as follows:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val spark: SparkSession = {
      SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local")
        .appName("spark pika")
        .getOrCreate()
    }
    val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv("/Users/siyuxiao/Downloads/churn_dataset_train.csv")
    df.show()
  }
}
```

But I got the following:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$
    at demo$.main(demo.scala:12)
    at demo.main(demo.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

How to fix this and read my csv file?
Here is my POM dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I really appreciate it if anyone can solve this.

Comment: Add please your pom file. And how you run your application?

Comment: Stackoeverflow does not let me to put all the POM code, because it is too much code. So I just put dependencies there. If you need all the POM, I can post a picture.

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) means java cannot find class in classpath. If you run it locally you must remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from pom.xml

pom.xml example:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spark.version>2.4.8</spark.version>
    <scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.12</scala.compat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.compat.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I once tried it but there is still error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer$.empty()Lscala/collection/GenTraversable;
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.<init>(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:69)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.<init>(SparkSession.scala:780)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.builder(SparkSession.scala:980)
 at demo$.main(demo.scala:12)
 at demo.main(demo.scala)

Comment: @xiao it look likes you have problem with scala versions compabiblity or you have multiple scala versions in classpath. Show all dependencies for scala. You must use only scala 11 for your spark version or change spark version

Comment: How to show all dependencies for scala? Would you please explain it more specifically?

Comment: @xiao It look like your IDE using not scala 11. You use spark version spark-core_2.11 for scala 11. You must switch you IDE settings for scala 11. I attach example pom - you can try use it

Comment: I check my Scala version: siyuxiao@Siyus-MBP:~/maven$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.8 -- Copyright 2002-2018, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

Comment: I use the same code with sbt and it works. Curious why with Maven it does not work?

Comment: I changed my pom.xml example - it must works for your spark version for scala 12. In your pom.xml you using spark dependencies for scala 11: spark-core_2.11. Change it to 2.12 and it must works

Comment: I think you write something: libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0" - without _2.11 postfix, sbt autouse right scala version